# Reversing word order in a string with C (error in code)

Tags: c

Could someone guide me in the right direction with this ?

This is a school assignment which i just cant seem to find the error in.
For the input

```
"a b c d e f"
```

i get

```
"f e d c b a" and that is right.
```

But for

```
"1234567890 abcdefghij" i get 

"�' abcdefghij 1234567890"
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction? Are the pointers all wrong ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{  
  char *words [100];
  char *word[11];
  char *str;
  int res, i;
  i = 0;
  res = scanf("%10s",word);
  if (res != 1) return 0;

  while ( res != EOF) {
    str = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
    strcpy(str,word);
    words[i] = str;
    res = scanf("%10s",word);
    i = i+1;
  }

  while (i>=0) {
    printf("%s ",words[i]);
    i--;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `char word[11];`.

Comment: When trying to compile your code, I get half a screen of warnings and a syntax error.  Did you listen to what your compiler says?

Comment: please fix the indentation. It hurts in my eyes

Comment: this question has been answered several times on stackoverflow.  Suggest a google search and/or a stackoverflow search to find one of the existing answers

Comment: Thanks for the tip and i'm sorry about the mess, really new to this but have been trying to watch videos and read tutorials.
Also reading through the other questions i couldn't find a solution to my problem

Answer (score 2):

`i` starts out 1 element past the end of the array. It's odd that the first example seems to work. Not surprising that the second does not.

Try:

```
while (--i >= 0)
{
  printf("%s ", words[i]);
}
```

and `word` should be `char word[11]`, not `char *word[11]`.

Comment: Thank you for the help.
For some reason the cloudcoder interface only accepts my output when i use * (probably just some bug).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `i` is one digit higher than the last filled index of your word so it is may potentially grab garbage.

instead of : `i = i+1;`

use:

```
if ( res != EOF) i = i+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use the `strrev(str)` function to reverse `str`? i think that one is an easy way out

Comment: Thanks for the tip and its a good one but i was not allowed to use any functions

Comment: FredMensah it's pretty common in this kind of homework to forbid the use of the `string.h` header. And also `strrev()` is not standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is int the print `loop`.

```
while (i>=0) {
    printf("%s ",words[i]);
    i--;
}
```

when you start this loop the value of `i` will give you an uninitialized element from the `words` array, change it this way

```
while (i > 0) {
    printf("%s ", words[--i]);
}
```

**note**: you should also `free` the pointers, so don't overwrite the words count, if it's only for ilustrative purpose, then it's ok, but even though you should do this

```
while (i > 0) {
    char *currentWord = words[--i];
    printf("%s ", currentWord);
    free(currentWord);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

It worked after i fixed the print loop.

Comment: @SnæbjörnValurLilliendahl I see that you don't have any accepted answers, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*function splits a string into an array of words, returns the array and its actual dimension*/
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
char **StringToWords (char *buf, int &dim, int NW, int LW)
{
    char **words = (char**) malloc (NW*sizeof(char*));  
    int i = 0;
    for (; i<NW; i++)
        words[i] = (char*)malloc (LW*sizeof(char));     

    i = -1;
    char *delims = " ,.-";
    char *pch = strtok (buf, delims);
    while (pch != NULL && i<NW)
    {
        strcpy(words[++i], pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    }
    dim = i+1;
    return words;
}

void DestroyWords (char **words, int NW)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<NW; i++)
        free (words[i]);
    free (words);
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main()
{
    int NW = 100;   /*maximum number of words*/
    int LW = 50;    /*maximum length of a word*/

    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    printf("Your string:\n");
    gets(buf);

    int dim = 0;
    char **words = StringToWords (buf, dim, NW, LW);
    printf("Reversed string:\n");

    int i = dim;
    while (--i >-1)
        printf("%s ", words[i]);

    DestroyWords (words, NW);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```